# SQL query without using any implicit/explicit joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables:

- MOTEL: motelID (PK), motelName, town
- ROOM:  roomID (PK), motelNo (PK), type, cost
- BOOKING: motelNo (PK), guestID (PK), dateFrom (PK), dateTo, roomID
- GUEST: guestID (PK), guestName, guestAddress

For this SQL database, I have two questions that I'm trying to answer:

1. Select all guestIDs that have the person's first name as 'John', and have a booking with an undefined dateTo. No explicit or implicit joins are allowed.

So far, I've done it using explicit joins to see how I might be able to avoid using joins. I don't know how to not use joins for this query, so that's what I'm asking for help on firstly.

My code so far:

```
SELECT GUEST.GUESTID 
FROM GUEST
INNER JOIN BOOKING ON BOOKING.GUESTID = GUEST.GUESTID 
WHERE BOOKING.DATETO IS NULL
  AND GUEST.GUESTNAME = 'John%';
```

2. Select the cost and roomID of all rooms at the motel named 'Jollife'. If the room is occupied (according to the database), state the guestName of the room occupier.

All dates are in the format yyyymmdd.

My code so far:

```
SELECT COST.PRICE, ROOM.ROOMID 
FROM ROOM
INNER JOIN MOTEL ON MOTEL.MOTELID = ROOM.MOTELID
FULL OUTER JOIN BOOKING ON ROOM.MOTELID = BOOKING.MOTELID
```

I've attempted to start this question by doing an inner join of 'ROOM' and 'MOTEL' based on the motelID, and then a full outer join with 'BOOKING' so that the 'dateTo' can be checked. I'm not sure where to go from here. This is in postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can use :

```
SELECT GUEST.GUESTID FROM GUEST    
WHERE  GUEST.GUESTNAME='John%'
and exists ( select top 1 1 ---This is faster then  * 
form BOOKING 
where BOOKING.GUESTID=GUEST.GUESTID  
and BOOKING.DATETO IS NULL
)
```

and for the second question you and do :

```
SELECT COST.PRICE, ROOM.ROOMID, case when booking.GuestId is not null then guest.guestName else 'Vacent' end as OcupiedBy FROM ROOM
INNER JOIN MOTEL ON MOTEL.MOTELID=ROOM.MOTELID
left join BOOKING ON ROOM.MOTELID=BOOKING.MOTELID
left join Guest on BOOKING.GUESTID=GUEST.GUESTID  
where motel.MotelName = 'Jollife'
```